# Query DB according to set of user Inputs - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, validation

I am very new to programming. I am working on an application which has 6 fields for user to enter input, and on basis of entered input I have to query rows from database.

This is the image of my form
[image]

And I have the following combination for input:

- Anumber
- Bnumber
- Anumber, Bnumber
- Anumber, Start Date/Time
- Anumber, Bnumber,Start Date/Time
- Bnumber, Start Date/Time
- Anumber, Start Date/Time, End Date/Time
- Bnumber, Start Date/Time, End Date/Time
- Anumber,Bnumber, Start Date/Time, End Date/Time

User can enter inputs in all the ways I have described above. And I have to query DB based upon user input.

Lets say User enters Anumber, Then my query will be

`Select * from table_name where Anumber = 'input'`

if user enters both anumber and bnumber then my query will be

`Select * from table_name where Anumber = 'input' AND bnumber = 'input2'`

AND SO ON ...

I am sharing a bit of my code to know people What I am exactly doing and what better can be done.

```
if (TextAnumber.isEmpty() && TextBnumber.isEmpty() && StrUserStartDate.isEmpty() && StrUserStartTime.isEmpty()
                && StrUserEndDate.isEmpty() && StrUserEndTime.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter At Least One Input");
        }

        if (StrUserStartDate.isEmpty() && !StrUserStartTime.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Start Date");
        }
        if (!StrUserStartDate.isEmpty() && StrUserStartTime.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Start Time");
        }

        if (StrUserEndDate.isEmpty() && !StrUserEndTime.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter End Date");
        }
        if (!StrUserEndDate.isEmpty() && StrUserEndTime.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter End Time");
        }

        if (!StrUserEndDate.isEmpty() && !StrUserEndTime.isEmpty() && StrUserStartDate.isEmpty()
                && StrUserStartTime.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Start Date/Time");
        }

        if (!TextAnumber.isEmpty() && TextBnumber.isEmpty() && StrUserStartDate.isEmpty() && StrUserEndDate.isEmpty()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "select anumber,bnumber FROM CDR WHERE ANUMBER = '" + TextAnumber + "' ORDER BY ANUMBER");
            while (rs.next()) {
                graphNodeA = rs.getString("ANUMBER");
                graphNodeB = rs.getString("BNUMBER");
                graph.addNode(graphNodeA);
                graph.addNode(graphNodeB);
                i++;
                graph.addEdge("string" + i, graphNodeA, graphNodeB);
            }
        }
        if (TextAnumber.isEmpty() && !TextBnumber.isEmpty() && StrUserStartDate.isEmpty() && StrUserEndDate.isEmpty()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "select anumber,bnumber FROM CDR WHERE ANUMBER = '" + TextBnumber + "' ORDER BY BNUMBER");
            while (rs.next()) {
                graphNodeA = rs.getString("BNUMBER");
                graphNodeB = rs.getString("ANUMBER");
                graph.addNode(graphNodeA);
                graph.addNode(graphNodeB);
                i++;
                graph.addEdge("string" + i, graphNodeA, graphNodeB);
            }
        }
        if (!TextAnumber.isEmpty() && !TextBnumber.isEmpty() && StrUserStartDate.isEmpty()
                && StrUserEndDate.isEmpty()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select anumber,bnumber FROM CDR WHERE ANUMBER = '" + TextAnumber
                    + "' AND BNUMBER = '" + TextBnumber + "' ORDER BY ANUMBER");
            while (rs.next()) {
                graphNodeA = rs.getString("ANUMBER");
                graphNodeB = rs.getString("BNUMBER");
                graph.addNode(graphNodeA);
                graph.addNode(graphNodeB);
                i++;
                graph.addEdge("string" + i, graphNodeA, graphNodeB);
            }
        }
```

For this, I am using `If/Else` which seems very complex to me and also code looks very rough.

**What I want here is, if there is any better solution for this kind of problem?**
I Hope I clear my problem here :)

Comment: What's the problem? This may be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To improve the code my suggestions would be that you use Hibernate criteria. It will not only improve your code but also prevent your application problems such as sql injection. For example say your hibernate class for the table is CDR.java you can handle the query as shown below:

```
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(CDR.class);
    if (!TextAnumber.isEmpty()) {
       cr.add(Restrictions.eq("ANUMBER", TextAnumber));
    }
    if (!TextBnumber.isEmpty()) {
       cr.add(Restrictions.eq("BNUMBER", TextBnumber));
    }
    //make sure to format your date to the right format
    if (!StrUserStartDate.isEmpty().isEmpty()) {
        cr.add(Restrictions.gt("StartDate",StrUserStartDate));
    }
    if (!StrUserEndDate.isEmpty().isEmpty()) {
      cr.add(Restrictions.lt("EndDate",StrUserEndDate));
    }

    List results = cr.list();
```

Another improvement is to create new methods for repeated code to improve readability and fixing of errors.

For more about hibernate refer to the documentation here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Here is a great tutorial about it too:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm